# Midrash - Avraham Avinu and the idol worshipper

Tags: sources-mekorot, avodah-zarah, abraham

A came across a Dvar Torah [here](https://adathisraelshul.org/e-torah/parsha/56-lech-lecha/403-point-to-ponder-lech-lecha-5775) which states the following:

> [The souls that they made in Charan (12:5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0) – Rav Ovadiah Yosef ztl. cited a midrash which described how far Avraham went in order to be mikarev someone. The Midrash as repeated by Rav Ovadiah ztl. described an elder who came to Avraham’s tent and, after receiving free hospitality took out his idol in order to offer thanks. Avraham demurred and tried to show him the error of his ways. After the conversation—of numerous hours-- the man again took out his idol. For the lack of respect, Avraham asked him to leave. Hashem appeared to Avraham and told him that He was waiting 90 years for the chance to have this man influenced by Avraham in order to have him see the error of his ways. Avraham sent for the man and encouraged the man to return. After extended conversation and a refill on the provisions, the man took out the idol and instead of praying to it, smashed it noting that the extended hospitality clearly demonstrated a higher belief system than the idol. Rav Ovadiah added that we clearly see the importance of not giving up on someone – even at 90 – and that Hashem still waits for him....

Does anyone know where this Midrash is?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask the author of the d'var you cite?

Comment: Thanks @MauriceMizrahi it was written 8 years ago and I have zero shaychus to this kehilla?

Comment: This site has their Rav's e-mail:  https://sites.libsyn.com/398573/when-religion-becomes-a-prison-identifying-treating-religious-ocd-with-rabbi-dr-jonathan-schwartz

Comment: Thank you @Maurice!

Comment: Maybe check Otzar Midrashim - Medrash Avraham Avinu

Comment: Thanks @Sam - I scanned through it and didn't see anything sadly.